# Erro de acentuação ao exportar dados do banco em xlxs com javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, banco-de-dados, exportação

estou dando manutenção em um código que lê dados de um banco MYSQL e via PHP transforma ele em uma tabela e com JQuery exporto ele com documento do Excel.
Entretanto a acentuação fica toda errada por exemplo:

```
Ãﾁrea de AtuaÃ§Ã£o  NÃºmero
```

O código que eu utilizo em Jquery é esse:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //creating a temporary HTML link element (they support setting file names)
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var data_type = 'data:application/x-msexcel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('dvData');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    a.download = 'Relatorio_Diplomas_Legais.xls';
    a.click();
});
```

Não encontrei o parâmetro que devo passar pra codificar o texto.
Alguem saberia me dizer oque poderia ser?